# Swift onesignal can I allow my app to support both ios 9 and ios 10 notifications

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, onesignal

I wonder if I can allow my app to support both ios 9 and ios 10 notifications?

I just integrated onesignal a notification service into my app and looked into the ios10 part which support videos/gifs etc.

So if I want to allow notifications into my app can I only support ios9 or can I support ios 10 as well, I mean if the notification falls back into ios 9 style if device runs that.

Right now I have this:

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "myId", handleNotificationReceived: { (notification) in
            print("Received Notification - \(notification?.payload.notificationID)")
        }, handleNotificationAction: { (result) in

            // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
            let payload = result?.notification.payload
            var fullMessage = payload?.title

            //Try to fetch the action selected
            if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData, let actionSelected = additionalData["actionSelected"] as? String {
                fullMessage =  fullMessage! + "\nPressed ButtonId:\(actionSelected)"
            }
            print(fullMessage)
        }, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : true, kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : OSNotificationDisplayType.notification.rawValue])

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationCategories { (categories) in
                let myAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "actionSelected", title: "Hit Me!", options: .foreground)
                let myCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myOSContentCategory", actions: [myAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)
                let mySet = NSSet(array: [myCategory]).addingObjects(from: categories) as! Set<UNNotificationCategory>
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(mySet)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set an iOS 10 media attachment on OneSignal's dashboard or REST API it will still be delivered to iOS 9 and older devices without the attachment.